# How to view the Flutter CLI first run welcome screen again

Tags: linux, flutter, ubuntu

I am developing with Flutter on Linux. I want to see the [welcome message](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/989f864497f59308896e8694c7d5d6a4ee65b36a/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/reporting/first_run.dart#L13-L40) that displays the first time you use the Flutter CLI.

There is a file in my home directory, `$HOME/.flutter` that has the following contents:

```
{
  "firstRun": false,
  "clientId": "355b8530-82af-4a01-9dbf-bc1b2f526ef3"
}
```

I've tried deleting this file. I've also tried changing the value of `firstRun` to `true`. Neither of these have worked, and still I haven't been able to trigger the original welcome message to display again when running the `flutter --version` CLI command. I've tried completely uninstalling flutter from my machine as well.

If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @mariofrancois that's completely unrelated to what I'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `~/.config/flutter/tool_state` file from your machine.